# How to enable SSL/TLS in Jboss fuse REST Service (JAX-RS)?

Tags: ssl, https, jax-rs, jbossfuse

I have created REST service using **JBossFuse JAX-RS**, the XML file is as below.
Can anyone help me to enable SSL/TLS to this service?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd               http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd         http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd         http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <jaxrs:server address="http://localhost:9000/employee" id="EmplRestService">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="EmplService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>  
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="EmplService" class="com.sample.beans.EmployeeServiceResource"/>     
</beans>
```

Thanks

Comment: I successfully sat up the SSL/TLS in REST Service  following instructions from below reference
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the absolute address
address="http://localhost:9000/employee"

You need configure httpj:engine-factory as described here[1]
[1]http://cxf.apache.org/docs/standalone-http-transport.html

Comment: I got a good point by your reference and lead it me a correct path. But got some issues. But I resolved them by the following reference. Thanks for your comment.
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html